# Strategy to write uncovered put and call

Tags: options, option-strategies

I found a strategy called "covered combo" where you sell 1 put, 1 call, and purchase 100 shares of the underlying; is there a name for doing this without purchasing the 100 shares?

Comment: It seems like you are looking for a [straddle](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straddle).

Comment: @skoestlmeier Yes! Thank you, I kept seeing "long straddle" in every "option strategy list" I looked up and it didn't occur to me to change "long" to "short".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy you are asking for is called [straddle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straddle). To be more precise, as you would like to **sell** one put and one call option, it is a *short straddle*.

Both options are referring to the same underlying security, strike price and expiration date. Be aware that it is a very risky strategy, as gains are limited and losses are not restricted.

---

#### Edit

The wikipedia article mentions

> The risk is virtually unlimited as large moves of the underlying security's price either up or down will cause losses proportional to the magnitude of the price move.

I called a straddle a *"very risky strategy"*, which should be true for many (often less informed) private investors, handling around with option-strategies and thus using derivatives in a speculative way. As stated in the comments, a straddle (as any derivative) is also very useful for other purposes than speculating.

Comment: Just extending this accurate answer - straddles are basic, and well traded, financial products calibrating the volatility. Personally I think *'very risky'* is subjective and not really reflective of the general opinion, especially in a liquid market and/or where dynamic delta hedges can be used to mitigate losses. Additionally the unlimited losses brought about by this product are not really any different to buying some instrument and having its price fall indefinitely, which I also would not really claim would be classed as very risky.

Comment: Must a straddle mean the same strike/expiration?

Comment: @Attack68 What does it mean to "calibrate the volatility"?

Comment: Implied Volatility is obviously a key component of option or swaption pricing. The physical at the money straddle prices are those that traders use to imply volatility at those points and as a result calibrate their entire surface (or cube) when they consider interpolation and other factors

Comment: @Attack68 +1 for your valid objection! Indeed, i just thought about a simple (private) investor handling around with some option-strategies following some online promise of 'become rich with day-trading in three days'. Thats why i appreciate QF Stack-Exchange: You are absolutely right with your comment and i give it credit in editing my answer.